# Magento Pagination not working properly

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I have installed the new magento theme and now i am facing the problem of pagination.
On Category page it is showing pagination correctly and href have correct link in it but when i click on it it redirect me to /p= page only no number is coming after p when i click on the link but it is working properly when copy the link and manually paste into browser.